# calendar item from Outlook exchange public in javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook, calendar, exchange-server, mapi

I need to get items from the public calendar in MS Outlook 2013. The company using Exchange 2010

This code no work

var ol = new ActiveXObject("outlook.application");

var calendar =ol.getnamespace("mapi").getdefaultfolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Items

Thank you

Comment: path is \test\test2

Comment: "no work"? What is the exact error? Are you running your script in IE from a site added to the safe list?